# How could I control multiple independent timed loops simultaneously within a general time limit in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I am working on programming two separate time loops to get random timings for two different speed updates for a random position machine I am making. I need to be able to have the frames of the machine update their speeds after random amounts of time during a set period of time for testing. I have been able to get two outcomes. The first outcome is not having any time limit or stop condition and each loop acts independently, which is shown in the first image. [image: Independent but uncontrollable system] The other outcome is both are able to be controlled, but only update when the largest time elapses (due to the encompassing while loop), which is shown in the second image.
[image: Image of while loop controlled system] How would I go about being able to control both loops (have them stop when the time limit elapses) and have them act independently (updating times as their own time elapses)

Thank you for your help!
The output right now is only to the specified file

To help clarify:

```
total_time = time_set_by_user
//for loop 1
while(total_time still going){
       pick random time and speed
       wait random time
       }
//for loop 2 (in parallel)
while(total_time still going){
       pick random time and speed
       wait random time
       }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are asking for here. Do the times coming out of these loops do anything other than get logged to the file? In the second image, your internal loops are only iterating once (TRUE to Stop, FALSE to Continue). Could you give a small pseudo code demonstration of what you want this to be doing?

Comment: I am not too stressed about writing anything. I don't really need an output, it was just there from checking the random number generator

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

Your first attempt is very close to a working solution, all you need to do is move your "Time Elapsed" express VI inside of the loops and check for the timeout within the loop.

Your stop flags in those loops are never reading high, hence your infinite loops.

## Explanation

The problem that you are struggling with here is a pretty common LabVIEW beginners issue, you are forgetting about the Dataflow paradigm.

Under the data-flow paradigm a loop will not be able to start until *ALL* of its inputs are available. In this case the order of operations would be:

Check Time Elapsed (False) -> Start Loops (False Stop Condition) -> Run Forever

You should actually be able to see this in operation if you enable the 'Highlight Execution' (Lightbulb button) inside your block diagram and run the code again.